# Selecting column and it's maximum length of the data frame using spark in java

Tags: java, dataframe, apache-spark, aggregate

I am new to spark.

I want to select column name and its maximum length of spark data frame in java.

I am using spark. I find few but those are in scala and python and those are not working in spark.
The input and expected out are as below.

I would like to find a length of the longest element in each column.

I try

```
df.select(Arrays.stream(df.columns().map(colname - > df.agg(max(length(col(colname))).head().get(0));
```

But not sure how to get data frame with column names and it's maximum length.

Regards,
Pramod

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close

```
    SparkSession spark =  SparkSession.builder()
            .config(new SparkConf()
            .setAppName("test")
            .setMaster("local[*]"))
            .getOrCreate();

    StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(new StructField[]{
            createStructField("col1", DataTypes.StringType, true),
            createStructField("col2", DataTypes.StringType, true),
            createStructField("col3", DataTypes.StringType, true)
    });

    List<Row> rows = Arrays.asList(
            RowFactory.create("aaa", "b","cc"),
            RowFactory.create("a", "bbbbbbb", "c"),
            RowFactory.create("aa", "bbb", "ccccc")
    );

    Dataset df = spark.createDataFrame(rows, schema);
    df.show();


    Dataset resultSingleRow = df.select(Arrays.stream(df.columns()).map(colname -> max(length(col(colname))).as(colname)).toArray(Column[]::new));
    resultSingleRow.show();

    // spark 3.4+
    Dataset resultMultipleRows = resultSingleRow.unpivot(new Column[]{}, "column-name", "length");
    resultMultipleRows.show();
```

Output:

```
+----+-------+-----+
|col1|   col2| col3|
+----+-------+-----+
| aaa|      b|   cc|
|   a|bbbbbbb|    c|
|  aa|    bbb|ccccc|
+----+-------+-----+


+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|   3|   7|   5|
+----+----+----+


+-----------+------+
|column-name|length|
+-----------+------+
|       col1|     3|
|       col2|     7|
|       col3|     5|
+-----------+------+
```

Comment: Thanks you. But This one is throwing GeneratedEvaluationClass exception. I wanted to select data frame with two columns. First column should be column name and second column should the maximum length of the data (String) of that column. Thank you for reply

Comment: I added the complete code that works just fine on my machine, so check what's different in your case. Once you have the result as a single row you can transform it to multiple rows by "unpivot" (assuming you use Spark 3.4+).

Comment: Thanks. It's working now. Actually I was using Arrays.Stream() so we should explicitly mention functions.max or functions.length or functions.col. So now it's working fine after using method with class.

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, consider to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).